# Why does a generic varargs method called from another generic method return Object[]?

Tags: java, generics, variadic-functions

I encountered the following code in Joshua Bloch's Effective Java book but I can't understand why the `pickTwo` method returns `Object[]`? The method `toArray` returns `Integer[]`. So why does `pickTwo` return `Object[]`? I think it should return `Integer[]`.

Joshua Bloch's book says that:

> The type of this array is determined by the compile-time types of the arguments passed in to the method, and the compiler may not have enough information to make an accurate determination. Because this method returns its varargs parameter array, `pickTwo` will always return an array of type `Object[]`.

```
public class JavaApplication52 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
     System.out.println(toArray(1,2,3));
     System.out.println(pickTwo(1,2,3));
    }

    static <T> T[] pickTwo(T a, T b, T c) {
        switch (ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(3)) {
            case 0:
                return toArray(a, b);
            case 1:
                return toArray(a, c);
            case 2:
                return toArray(b, c);
        }
        throw new AssertionError(); // Can't get here
    }

    static <T> T[] toArray(T... args) {
        return args;
    }
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
[Ljava.lang.Integer;@6d06d69c
[Ljava.lang.Object;@70dea4e
```

Comment: The erasure of `T` is `Object`, so the erasure of `T[]` is `Object[]`.

Comment: @DanielPryden I'm going to assume the OP does not understand the concept of erasure in the compiler (I barely do).  Does my gross wording below capture the gist of it?

Comment: @DanielPryden I’m sure this question is a duplicate, but not of that question. This question is specifically about varargs.

Comment: Yes, more or less. The authoritative Java language specification actually explains erasure reasonably well. The basic idea is that compile-time types and runtime types, while related to each other, are not actually the same thing. This is true (to one degree or another) in practically every programming language I know, so it's not a fundamentally strange concept. But the rules for exactly what runtime type an expression has, relative to its compile-time type, are... subtle, to say the least. And as each version of Java adds more complex type inference rules, it keeps getting more complicated.

Comment: @cppbeginner: Yes, I was searching for a good duplicate and I couldn't find a great one, but it's easy to edit the duplicate list. Do you have a link to a better duplicate?

Comment: @cppbeginner: OK, I found a better duplicate. How does that look?

Comment: Looks like a much better duplicate.

Comment: @ Daniel Pryden  Thanks.I didn't know that type information erase by erasure.

Answer (score 2):

You've explained yourself in your question.  Since `pickTwo()` takes generics, when it calls `toArray()` the compiler has no idea with what class would have been passed to `pickTwo()` then used when calling `toArray()`.  Since that can only be known at runtime, you just get `Object`  (`[Ljava.lang.Object;@70dea4e`))

When you call `toArray()` explicitly with `int`'s at compile time the compiler can determine what the return type will be.